# Java client using client-auth works in code but not with vm-arguments

Tags: java, ssl, jvm-arguments, mutual-authentication

I have created a keypair with keytool for client authentication. From this file I exported the public key as certificate for the server to authenticate the client.

**Client setup:**
 Loaded the server certificate into a truststore file and used the keystore file as keystore. The client works when I load truststore and keystore via code with SSLContext and using Apache HttpClient:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
              keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("keystore"), keyPassphrase.toCharArray());
              SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(new File("truststore"), trustPassphrase.toCharArray(),
                        new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore,keyPassphrase.toCharArray())
                .build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslcontext,
                new String[] {"TLSv1"},   
                null,
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
              CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                .build();
```

The ssl output shows that the client presents the certificate chain. Setting the keystore with SoapUI also works fine.

**My Problem:** Providing the same truststore and keystore via vm-arguments (not using SSLContext) I see that the client doesn't present the certificate chain in the ssl output.
 
**VM args:**

```
    -Djavax.net.debug=ssl 
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS 
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore 
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keystorepw
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks 
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore 
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=truststorepw
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typo in your VM argument: you have `trustore` as the arg value, whereas your code used `truststore`. I hope it really is this simple.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo - but this isn't the reason. And I am more worried about the keystore... as this doesn't seem to present the certificate to the server.